# Windows 2008 r2 2 node cluster - one node unavailable

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, cluster

I have 2 node Windows 2008 r2 cluster, i failed over service onto node2, restarted node1, and after restart node1 is unavailable. The networks interfaces will not come up and both interface are unavailable.

Server setup:

On 2 vmware esxi 5 on fiber san, disk are pRDMs. 2 windows 2008 r2 sp1 full patched up to Jan 2012. The cluster has been working for 3 months with multi reboots. I have the exact same cluster setup working just fine.

event log errors:

```
event id: 1573
Node1 failed to form a cluster. This was because the witness was not accessible. Please ensure that the witness resource is online and available.

eventid: 1069
Cluster resource 'Quorum' in clustered service or application 'Cluster Group' failed.

eventid: 7024
The Network Location Awareness service terminated with service-specific error %%-1073741288.

services unable to start 
base filtering engine - Error 5: Access is denied

dhcp client (running static ip address) - Error 5: Access is denied
IKE and AuthIP IPsec keying - Error 1068: the dependency service or group failed to start

network list services  - Error 1068: the dependency service or group failed to start

network location awareness - event id 7024 - The Network Location Awareness service terminated with service-specific error %%-1073741288.
```

Comment: These are virtualised servers? What's the network adapter status from within the console of the VM?

Comment: yes, both nic are active and showing packets.

Answer (score 1):

> The networks interfaces will not come up and both interface are unavailable.

Found your problem. You need to fix that.

Comment: How to fix the network interface that are unavailable? I am able to RDP into the server and I see packets going back and forward on both interfaces.

Comment: Where can you see packets going back and forth on the interfaces? Where do you see that they are "not up" and "unavailable"?

Comment: Under Network Connections > status of the adapter. In failover cluster manager > cluster > networks.

Comment: You haven't changed any of the network configuration have you? If you right click the network in Failover and show the critical events do you have anything other than event id 1130?

Comment: The DBA add redgate sqlbackup 6.5 non cluster version to the two nodes in the cluster. I removed the software and still get private interface is unreachable. I can ping the private IP address and get a reply. I can move the application between the two nodes now without failing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, because the problem is with permissions of the services at the registry level, at the SO, not at Vmware.

To solve it, just Run a Command Prompt (as Administrator) on the SO and execute the following commands:

```
net localgroup administrators localservice /add
net localgroup administrators networkservice /add
```

Reboot and thats it: both services should be up and running!